# What's the meaning of "WHEN ? THEN"?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

While reading some source code, I just stumbled upon the following piece of code in Progress:

```
WHEN ? THEN
...
```

In other languages, I've seen code like `IF TRUE THEN ...` (this code is always to be run) or `IF FALSE THEN ...` (this code is never to be run).

As `?` means "nothing" in Progress, does this piece of code mean the same as `IF FALSE THEN ...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's used in a CASE statement, it compares the value used in the CASE block to the unknown value. That's similar to a switch statement in C-like languages.

```
CASE lOk:
    WHEN TRUE THEN ...
    WHEN FALSE THEN ...
    WHEN ? THEN ...
END CASE .
```

Comment: I've just verified a bit furter: it's inside a CASE statement, saying `WHEN 0 THEN ... WHEN ? THEN ... OTHERWISE ...`. According to your answer, the `OTHERWISE` case will never be triggered. Is this correct?

Comment: In this case, no, since there are only 3 valid values for logical/boolean data types. But if you used a character or numerical value as the expression, then it's more likely that you'll have an `OTHERWISE` .

Comment: ? is the unknown value - not /any/ value - see https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/Special-character.html

Answer (score 0):

In the expression

```
WHEN value[ OR WHEN value] . . . THEN
```

Each value is an expression that evaluates to a possible value for expression. If value matches the current value of expression, then the associated block or statement executes. The question now is, how to evaluate to an unknown or null value. This is done with the "?" character. For example:

```
IF myVariable = ? THEN DISPLAY "This value is unknown".
```

If instead you need to evaluate a comparison to an actual question mark character, all you need to do is enclose the question mark in single or double quotes.

```
IF myVariable = '?' THEN DISPLAY "This is a question mark".
IF myVariable = "?" THEN DISPLAY "This is a question mark".
```

For future reference, [Progress Knowledgebase](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/) is a good place to get information.